# Running nodejs + Nest + typescript application using Node

Tags: node.js, typescript, debugging, intellij-idea

Trying to run the application built on Node, Nest and Typescript. I have following main.ts file.

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { VersioningType } from '@nestjs/common';

// Extending the string prototype
String.prototype.toSentence = function (sep) {
  sep = sep || ' ';
  return this.split(sep)
    .map((v) => v.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + v.slice(1))
    .join(sep);
};

function bootstrap() {
  NestFactory.create(AppModule, { bodyParser: true, cors: true })
    .then((app) => app.enableVersioning({ defaultVersion: '1', type: VersioningType.URI, prefix: 'v' }))
    .then((app) => app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0'));
}

bootstrap();
```

Following package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix"
  },
```

And following IntelliJ configuration,

[image: Configuration for NodeJS]

I am new to NodeJS and I am trying above things but not working for me, this is also causing me problem to debug the application.

However I can start the application using "yarn start:dev" and other options but as per the IntelliJ documentation I am following this process to start and debug the app.

Here is the link> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#ws_node_debug_from_run_tw

Let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: what issues starting with Node.js run configuration have you faced?

Comment: Compilation failures

Comment: you can try a recipe from https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/993#issuecomment-573584009, for example

Comment: I tried these things, it is not working for me and hence posting it again.

Answer (score 0):

IDK what compilation errors you are getting but the Run configuration you have there did not work for me. Try changing the Javascript file to dist/main.js. This worked for me.